# Best Practices for Naming Executable (EXE)

Tags: .net, executable

Our .net executable project is called "`<CompanyName>.<ProductName>.Client`", and we've set the assembly name for the project "`<ProductName>.exe`" - Seems legit, right?

A co-worker asked me this:
Why won't we call it simply "`<CompanyName>.<ProductName>.Client.exe`"?, and I couldn't back any answer with any article or best-practices guide.

What are the best practices of naming an executable, and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c:\program files\company name\product name\executable_name.exe`

**Update for @Oded:**
As you can see, the usual placement path of executables contains both company and product names so there is no need to repeat yourself.

For internal products/tools I personally use full names.

Don't use spaces in executable names, it'll make you use quotes in command line.

Comment: That's not answering the question - the placement of the executable is one thing, its actual name is another.

Comment: (You meant "product name.exe", right?) I'd like to add: keep your names *short*

Comment: @Oded it kinda explains why executable name should not contain company and product name

Comment: Kinda. Why not be explicit about it and add that to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are no "best practices". You do what makes sense.

In terms of naming the `exe`, it makes sense to keep the name short and descriptive, so when users see it (either in the directory or in the process list) it is simple and not encumbered by the extra stuff they do not care about. In these terms, it also makes some support work easier.

Answer (score 0):

Naming a DLL after its root namespace is a common and reasonable convention (but not universal: e.g. the WPF assembly `WindowsBase.dll`, isn't named after a namespace, probably because it doesn't really have a well-defined root namespace).

But this isn't necessary for executables.

One tiny advantage of using a different convention for executables (`ProductName.exe` rather than `CompanyName.ProductName.Client.exe`) is that the executable is easier to find in Windows Explorer - no need to search through a list of files with similar names to find the executable hiding in the middle:

```
CompanyName.ProductName.Component1.dll
CompanyName.ProductName.Component1.xml
CompanyName.ProductName.Component2.dll
CompanyName.ProductName.Component2.xml
CompanyName.ProductName.Component3.dll
CompanyName.ProductName.Component3.xml
...
```

Comment: I would add that this is a bad idea in general as the file names can become fairly long and depending on the depth of the solution it is fairly easy to reach the max file name length for windows